# How to check for nil? for variables in ERB

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

File `main.rb`:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

File `views/index.html.erb`:

```rb
Hello, <%= name unless name.nil? %>
```

Now run the application and check the URL. It says

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `name'
```

Apparently `name.nil?` doesn't work.

How can I "render something if it exists" using ERB templates in a Sinatra app?

Comment: `name` is never defined, that's not even nil. You can try with `defined?` (`foo if defined?(foo) && !foo.nil? # nil`)

Comment: @SebastianPalma Is it a special case for `var = something unless var.nil?` where an undefined variable returns `true` for `#nil?`?

Comment: Sorry @iBug, I didn't understand your question, would you mind?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thank you anyways. Never mind. I solved it with Google. To be specific, `a = 1 if a.nil?` doesn't fail when `a` is undefined, but `a.nil? if a.nil?` does. It's special for assignment operations regarding postfix conditions.

Comment: @SebastianPalma You can get the green tick if you change your first comment into an answer.

Comment: This really isn't a Sinatra or ERB question; It's a Ruby question with Sinatra and ERB being innocent bystanders.